# java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException waiting a Future

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I need to wait `SourceQueueWithComplete.offer` to finish:

```
  val config = ConfigFactory.defaultApplication()
  implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("TestSystem", config)
  implicit val mat: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val ctx = system.dispatcher

  val queue =
    Source.queue(5, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
      .async
      .mapAsync(8) { x: Int =>
        Future {
          println(s"Processed $x")
          x
        }
      }
      .to(Sink.ignore)
      .run()

  for (i <- 1 to 10) {
    println(s"Queueing $i...")
    for (_ <- queue.offer(i))
      println(s"$i has been queued!")
  }
```

output:

```
Queueing 1...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
Queueing 2...
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
Queueing 3...
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
Queueing 4...
    at Node1$.delayedEndpoint$Node1$1(Node1.scala:95)
Queueing 5...
    at Node1$delayedInit$body.apply(Node1.scala:12)
Queueing 6...
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
Queueing 7...
Queueing 8...
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)
Queueing 9...
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
Queueing 10...
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
    at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
    at Node1$.main(Node1.scala:12)
    at Node1.main(Node1.scala)
1 has been queued!
2 has been queued!
4 has been queued!
5 has been queued!
3 has been queued!
6 has been queued!
Processed 1
Processed 2
Processed 3
Processed 4
Processed 5
Processed 6
```

Enclosing `queue.offer` within a `synchronized` block does not help.

Comment: You probably should show more of your code. Particularly what is at and aroind the line **_Node1.scala:95_** that is reference in the stack trace as the one calling `Object.wait`.

Answer (score 1):

The errors suggest something related to[`DelayedInit`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala/DelayedInit.html), which is deprecated since Scala 2.11.0 (from the Scaladoc: "`DelayedInit` semantics can be surprising."). Presumably you're using [`App`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala/App.html), which extends `DelayedInit`, but it's difficult to diagnose how that might be a problem without seeing more of your code.

Also, you can use another `Source` to offer elements to the queue. The following works:

```
import akka.stream._
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import scala.concurrent._

object Main extends App {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("TestApp")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val ec = system.dispatcher

  val queue =
    Source.queue(5, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
          .async
          .mapAsync(8) { x: Int => Future(x) }
          .to(Sink.foreach(y => println(s"Processed: $y")))
          .run()

  Source(1 to 10)  
    .mapAsync(1) { x =>
      println(s"Offering: $x")
      queue.offer(x)
    }
    .runWith(Sink.ignore)
}
```

Comment: Isn't that true that `App` still extends `DelayedInit` and that stack trace for the line `queue = ...` in your code would contain something like `Main$.delayedEndpoint$Main$1` just like it does in the OP question? In other words, how do you see that OP uses `DelayedInit` explicitly rather than just `App`?

Comment: @SergGr: I didn't realize that `App` extends `DelayedInit`. Thanks for pointing that out.